# Merging K lists with N items doesnt work for big K or N(K or N > 200)

Tags: c++, algorithm, merge

I implemented an algorithm for merging K sorted lists with N items. The code works good for small input data but for N,K greater than 200 it will crash. I need to evaluate this algorithm so i need lists that have over 1000 length.

I tested all the functions needed including the construction of the MinHeap, all works good.

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct List {
    int size;
    Node* head;
};

struct HeapObject {
    int listIndex;
    int key;
};
Node* addNode(List* list, int data){
    auto* node = new Node;
    node->data = data;
    node->next = nullptr;
    ++list->size;
    if(list->head == nullptr) list->head = node;
    else
    {
        node->next = list->head;
        list->head = node;
    }
    return node;
}

List* newList(){
    auto* list = new List;
    list->size = 0;
    list->head = nullptr;
    return list;
}

List* generateSortedList(int size){
    auto* arr = new int[size];
    List* list = newList();
    FillRandomArray(arr,size,100,50000,true,2);//generate arrays with random elements in descending order, i cant provide that function since its in another header.
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        addNode(list,arr[i]);
    }
    return list;
}

List* generateLists(int k, int n){
    auto* lists = new List[k];
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        lists[i] = *generateSortedList(n);
    }
    return lists;
}
int parent(int i) {
    return (i-1)/ 2;
}

void topDownMinHeap(HeapObject* heap, int size) {
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        int j = i;
        while (j > 0 && heap[j].key < heap[parent(j)].key) {
            swap(heap[j], heap[parent(j)]);
            j = parent(j);
        }
    }
}

void pop(List* list){
    Node* aux = list->head;
    list->head = list->head->next;
    delete aux;
    --list->size;
}
void merge(List* lists, int k, int n, int* output)
{
    auto* minHeap = new HeapObject[k];

    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        minHeap[i].key = lists[i].head->data;
        minHeap[i].listIndex = i;
    }

    topDownMinHeap(minHeap,k);

    for(int i = 0; i < n * k; i++){
        output[i] = minHeap[0].key;
        pop(&lists[minHeap[0].listIndex]);
        if(lists[minHeap[0].listIndex].size != 0) minHeap[0].key = lists[minHeap[0].listIndex].head->data;
        else minHeap[0].key = INT32_MAX;
        topDownMinHeap(minHeap,k);
    }
}
int main() {
    int* output = new int[1000];
    List* lists = generateLists(100,50);
    merge(lists,100,50,output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The shown code fails to meet all requirements of a [mre] as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], and because of that nobody will be able to help you. See [ask] questions, for more information.

Comment: You're not too far from reproducible, the code can almost be compiled and run, and after that it might reproduce. Unfortunately you have abandoned minimal in the process. The reason you want both is it helps you zoom in on the bug. Ultimately a [mcve] would be a program that is 100% bug, and at that point you can't help but see the problem. You might not understand it and still need to ask a question, but typically you take a couple passes at reducing the code and the better signal to noise ratio reveals enough of the problem for you to fix it yourself.

Comment: Where does it crash? (See [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) if you do not know how to figure out where it crashes.) Can you trim down the example to something simpler while still demonstrating the crash?

Comment: I solved the problem by chance, I changed the function merge such that it will return the array "output", anyway I dont understand where was the problem. I initialized in the main function the ouput array with enough space, it doesnt look different for me but the program says the contrary.